# Dry run for analyzing wake-on-lan problems

Tags: wakeonlan

*Note* I had wake-on-lan working on an older kernel but after an upgrade, it now fails to wake up the machine.

I read in a forum to open a terminal and enter `journalctl -f` on the machine to wake up and enter `wakeonlan <mac_address>` on a different machine. (If I listen with `nc -ul -p 9` I do receive the magic packet.)

**Q1** Should there be any observable output from `wakeonlan` in the journal?

**Q2** Is there some kind of dry run to troubleshoot wake-on-lan problems?

Comment: The magic packet is typically sent as a UDP datagram to port 0,7 or 9, or directly over Ethernet as EtherType 0x0842. Maybe you will have to permit inbound traffic to UDP 7,9 on you target host.

Comment: @cmak.fr As I mentioned in the parenthesis above, I'm able to observe the magic-packet when the target machine is on and I listen with `nc`.